# How do I recover from a failed rx chain?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, rx-swift, flatmap

Rx seem a bit fragile in that it closes down an entire chain if one single thing doesn't work. That has become a real problem in my code as I have a chain that requests parameters through `ble`. First we ask for `ids`, then `definitions` which is sort of mapping min and max values, lastly it asks for the actual `parameters`:

```
override func getParameters() -> Single<[ParameterModel?]> {
    parameterCounter = 0
    parameterDefinitionCounter = 0
    
    return getParamterIds().do(onSuccess: { [weak self] values in
        self?.numberOfParameterIds = Float(values?.count ?? 0)
    })
        .flatMap { ids in
            Single.zip(ids!.compactMap { self.getParamterDefinition(id: $0) }) }
        .flatMap { parameters in
            Single.zip(parameters.compactMap { self.getParameter(id: $0!.id) }) }
}
```

So if we get an `array` with 30 `parameter ids`, it goes into `getParamterDefinition(id: $0)`. And if it fails on a single one of those, which it does, the whole thing closes down and `self.getParameter(id: $0!.id)` is never run. So even though 29 `parameters` pass through `getParamterDefinition(id: $0)` nothing is passed to `self.getParameter(id: $0!.id)`.

How do I recover from an error and keep going in the chain so that those that were successful in `getParamterDefinition(id: $0)` gets passed to `self.getParameter(id: $0!.id)` and gets displayed to the user?

*** UPDATE ***
This is the final result for anyone interested in solving issues like these:

```
override func getParameters() -> Single<[ParameterModel?]> {
        parameterCounter = 0
        parameterDefinitionCounter = 0
        
        func getFailedParameter(id: Int) -> ParameterModel {
            return ParameterModel(id: id, name: String(format: "tech_app_failed_getting_parameter".localized(), "\(id)"), min: 2000,
                                  max: 21600000, defaultValue: 2500, value: 2500,
                                  unit: "ms", access: 0, freezeFlag: 0,
                                  multiplicator: 1, operatorByte: 1, brand: 0,
                                  states: nil, didFailRetrievingParameter: true)
        }
        
        return getParamterIds().do(onSuccess: { [weak self] values in
            self?.numberOfParameterIds = Float(values?.count ?? 0)
        }).catchError { _ in return Single.just([]) }
            .flatMap { ids in
                Single.zip(ids!.compactMap { id in
                    self.getParamterDefinition(id: id).catchError { [weak self] _ in
                        self?.parameterErrorStatusRelay.accept(String(format: "tech_app_parameter_definition_error_status".localized(), "\(id)"))
                        return Single.just(getFailedParameter(id: id))
                    }
                })
            }
            .flatMap { parameters in
                Single.zip(parameters.compactMap { parameter in
                    guard let parameter = parameter, !(parameter.didFailRetrievingParameter) else {
                        return Single.just(parameter)
                    }
                    
                    return self.getParameter(id: parameter.id).catchError { [weak self] _ in
                        self?.parameterErrorStatusRelay.accept(String(format: "tech_app_parameter_error_status".localized(), "\(parameter.id)"))
                        return Single.just(getFailedParameter(id: parameter.id))
                    }
                })
            }
    }
```

Comment: Remember, in synchronous programming an entire chain of functions will close down if a single one throws. Think of an error emitted by an Observable the same way you think of a throwing function throwing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`Catch` methods](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/main/RxSwift/Observables/Catch.swift) to handle errors, you can use these to stop your sequence from terminating when an error event occurs.

A simple example that just ignores any errors would be to return nil whenever your `getParamterDefinition` observable emits an error:

```
override func getParameters() -> Single<[ParameterModel?]> {
    return getParameterIds()
        .do(onSuccess: { [weak self] values in
            self?.numberOfParameterIds = Float(values?.count ?? 0)
        })
        .flatMap { ids in
            Single.zip(
                ids!.compactMap {
                    self.getParameterDefinition(id: $0)?
                        .catchAndReturn(nil)
                }
            )
        }
        .flatMap { parameters in
            Single.zip(
                parameters.compactMap { parameter in
                    parameter.flatMap { self.getParameter(id: $0.id) }
                }
            )
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Catching errors with rx worked great! I did a variation of this posted above for anyone interested :)